# What are multiple greater/less than in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was reading an article at [www.codemag.com/article/1208111](http://www.codemag.com/article/1208111) and saw cases in the WHERE clauses where columns were compared with

```
Column1 <<<>> Column2
```

And

```
Column1 <<<= Column2
```

In Listing 13 and Listing 14 in the article

What does those mean?

Comment: I saw in my own looking that article below and got syntax errors when I tried, but I chalked it up to just something that was maybe version specific or maybe even tool specific, so it’s good to see it’s probably just an error altogether

Answer (score 5):

I believe the article is suffering from XML/style sheet issues with < signs. Here are the valid SQL comparison operators:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4):

It's invalid syntax, and likely a plugin formatting error.

For instance, this fails

`SELECT *
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id <<>> 1`

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error

Query 1:

```
select 1 where getdate()-1 <= GETDATE()
```

result:

```
-----------
1
```

Query 2:

```
select 1 where getdate()-1 <<<= GETDATE()
```

result:

```
Syntax error near '<'.
```